# How can I verify that an erlang process is hibernated?

Tags: erlang, elixir

Is there a way to verify that an erlang process has been indeed hibernated.
`erlang:process_info/1` doesn't seem to provide this information and I can't think of anything else which might.

Comment: If you're solely looking for Erlang on this, please remove the `elixir` tag.

Comment: It's the same in elixir. The processes in elixir are still "erlang" processes, as they run on the EVM - Erlang Virtual Machine

Comment: Well up till you posted your answer there was only an Erlang answer listed so I figured you only cared about Erlang.  No, it's not the same in Elixir--the syntax is different. It's _analogous_ but it's a different syntax.

Comment: Semantically it's the same, the byte code that is being executed is the same and the variables being queried and returned are the same. In my book (where I mix Erlang and Elixir on a daily basis) it's the same. And every Elixir (only) programmer can easily benefit from this answer if they happen to find it via a search. I don't really see why would anyone deny them this knowledge, by removing the tag. But yeah, here you go, have your explicit Elixir answer :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Its current function should be `erlang:hibernate/3`.

```
1> erlang:process_info(Pid, current_function).
 {current_function,{erlang, hibernate, 3}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to do the same in Elixir:

```
iex(2)> :erlang.process_info(pid, :current_function)
{:current_function, {:erlang, :hibernate, 3}}
```